# Bibliography in USPTO application

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-uspto-patent-and-response-letters/qtzkqddwxjbj) for writing my patent application. The template contains the following in the `config/config.tex` file.

```
\bibliographystyle{config/patent}
```

To add citations, I first create the `refs.bib` file in the root of the project, with the following content.

```
@article{test,
  author = {Author, A.},
  title = {Test Title},
  journal = {Test Journal},
  year = {2020},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1-2}
}
```

then tried to add references in the `patent.tex` file as the following.

```
\heading{DETAILED DESCRIPTION}

TEST~\cite{test}

\bibliography{references}
```

However, this leads to PDF file that neither contains the bibliography section nor the reference `test` (empty space shown). I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Welcome! Did you run BibTeX and then compile a second time?

Comment: Thank you!! I am actually running this on Overleaf, and tried their "Recompile from scratch" option with no joy. After replacing `\bibliographystyle{config/patent}` with `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`, I can see the reference section added, but still the citations do not appear in the text (i.e., the `TEST~\cite{test}` part).

Comment: The project doesn't include `patent.bst` so the code cannot possibly work.

Comment: That is correct, so that is why I switched to `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`, which still fails.

Comment: Honestly, I would forget this template and start from scratch. Anything this problematic at the very get-go is only going to get worse when you try to adapt it to your own content.

Comment: That is a very true answer!! I know it is probably not the correct question on this forum, but do you know of any good templates for USPTO?

Comment: Sorry, no. I'd never even heard of USPTO until I read your question. But often it is best to just start from a standard class unless the organisation itself provides something.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Also, if you get stuck, starting from a standard class and posting here is more likely to get you solutions than if you're trying to use a template. People know templates tend to be problematic and also very seductive. Neither disentangling the issue nor persuading somebody to change their entire setup is an especially attractive puzzle to solve, whereas how to do some technical thing X is. (At least, for people who tend to answer questions here.)

Comment: That is all very useful, thank you!